# Hausdorff distance.

Tags: analysis, hausdorff-distance

Let $A\in K_{c} (R^{p} ) $ and $u_0\in\mathbb{S} ^p$.  Define $v_A:= \sup_{v\in A} \langle u_0, v\rangle$. My question is the following, there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $B\in K_c(\mathbb{R} ^p) $, with $d_{H} (A, B) <\epsilon $, we have that $|v_B - v_A|<\epsilon$?.

Where $d_{H} $ is the Hausdorff distance and $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is the dot product.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $K_C(R^p)$? Is it the set of non-empty compact subsets of $\Bbb{R}^p$? Similarly, is $\Bbb{S}^p$ the unit sphere of $\Bbb{R}^p$?

Comment: If so, then we have $|v_A - v_B| \le d_H(A, B)$, i.e. the map from $A \mapsto \operatorname{supp}_A(u_0)$ is non-expansive.

Comment: @user759562 yes